# Display div only in high resolutions

Tags: html, css

I've made a website that stretch a container to the bottom. In that container, there are divs that fit perfectly the screen at low resolution such as 1366x768 ...etc

But when the resolution is higher (1440x900...etc) There is a blank space left under the divs [(link to view website at different resolutions)](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//csg0.com&w=1440&h=900&a=1&s=1)

So is there a possibility to fill that space with divs only in high resolution ? I've tried `overflow-y:hidden`,but since the container's height must be in auto it doesn't affect it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you might want to read up on [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) which enables you to set custom css for given resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#resolution) that target resolution like

```
@media screen and (min-resolution: 300dpi) { 
    #myDiv{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Alternatviely, you can target dimension such as width like

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) { 
    #myDiv{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `print` query for `screen`? Why not `@media screen and (min-width:1400px)`?

Comment: No problem. But you should also change `min-resolution` to `min-width` and set a pixel width and not `dpi`.